# java declaring array of texts from file as double

Tags: java, arrays, file, double

I am having some difficulty declaring an array on the text in a file. In other words, I am trying to store the information on a file into an array as double[] and displaying the array with the enhanced for loop. The file just contains 12 decimal numbers. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
 // create inFile2 variable
    Scanner inFile2 = new Scanner("/Users/timothylee/KeyWestHumid.txt");

    // while statment for inFile2
    while(inFile2.hasNext()){

        // create double reader
        double num2 = inFile2.nextDouble();

        double[] humidity1 = new double[num2];

        // for-each loop for displaying humidity
        for(double humidity : humidity1){

            // display array for humidity
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The enhanced for loop is only useful for looking at the values in an array/collection already.  Java doesn't do pass by reference so your `double humidity` field is just a copy, not a reference to the array.

You need to do something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < humidity1.length; i++) 
    humidity1[i] = inFile2.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try now, there are two issues in your code:

First by using Scanner this way:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("Bla.txt");
```

Will return 'Bla.txt' when calling s.nextLine(). To get the file content you need to pass a File object to your scanner like this:

```
Scanner inFile2 = new Scanner(new File("/Users/timothylee/KeyWestHumid.txt"));
```

The second issue is on how to fill those values into an array, here is my approach on doing so:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    try {

        //Initiate the scanner to read the files content 
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("D:\\temp\\backup_branch\\test.txt"));

        //Have something to care about array dimensions (see note about this in the answer!)
        List<Double> numbersFromFile = new ArrayList<Double>();

        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            double num2 = scanner.nextDouble();
            //add every number
            numbersFromFile.add(num2);
        }

        //Have it as array
        //Object[] vals = numbersFromFile.toArray();
        //double d = (double) vals[0];
        //System.out.println(d);

        //Print it 
        for(Double d : numbersFromFile){
            System.out.println(d);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Note: I seem to have a lack when it comes to generics and primitive types so dont rely on the generic part of this solution. It is more about to show you that you first want to fill your array with data and then use the new for-loop to iterate over an existing array.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:\\usr\\a.txt"));
double[] darray = new double[12];
int i=0;
while (s.hasNextDouble()) {
    darray[i++] = s.nextDouble();
}
for (double d : darray) {
    System.out.println(d);
}
```